# Oracle Datareader in .Net - way too slow (over network)

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, datareader, oracleclient

Before I get the "have you tried ODP.net?" answers, yes I have and am using it now.

I'm moving data from oracle to sql server (not important) and am using a datareader on the oracle connection. Larger tables are CRAWLING. Sometimes as bad as 10 records per second. When I noticed the performance issues, I reduced my source code down to just doing simple Reader.Read() calls over the whole table, so nothing else is slowing it. I've tried both the MS and the Oracle ODP .net clients. I'm currently using the 11g Instant Client, 64bit on win7 64bit, 8 gigs ram and all the goodies. I've used it on the local network, and am currently ona  VPN and the performance is basically the same. I've tuned the Prefetch sizes with no results.

I can run the Export Data function in the Oracle Sql DEveloper tools, and export all the data for the entire database, on this same machine, over the same network, at about 100 times the speed.

I can copy my .net app to the oracle server and run the same performance test on it, and it finishes in less than a second.

So, it's not the network itself being slow and it's not the quantity of data (as demonstrated by SqlDeveloper export), and it's not the .net code itself nor is it the oracle db (as demonstrated by running it on the server), so it has to be some combination of Datareader used over any network.

Is it my instant client install? Does the full blown client perform better? 64 bit client messing things up? Really at a loss.

UPDATE:

I've since run the same app, compiled for 32 bit, and run on a virtual pc instance of windows xp which has the "full" oracle client installed (32 bit version, obviously). Even with the reduced performance of a VM, it still ran almost 10 times faster. So, definitely some sort of problem with the Instant client, and my guess specifically the 64 bit Instant Client. The last test to confirm this would be to install a 32 bit instant client on this same machine and run it again. If i can find the time...

Comment: This is 2 days old, so I suspect you've moved on.  I wonder what your connection string looks like?  Make sure you're not doing something wonky like using Oracle OraOLEDB plumbing in the client.

Comment: I'm currently using the "tns style" connection string, but from my code instead.. like: SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;

Comment: Nothing obvious there.  We usually use tnsnames.ora, but it should be the same.  I've seen weird slowness in the past with "provider=oraOlEDB"...

Comment: I'm suspecting the 64 bit Instant Client, I'll be trying next on a 32 bit "fulll install" client machine, still over the same network, and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

"I can copy my .net app to the oracle server and run the same performance test on it, and it finishes in less than a second."

This is the root of your solution.   Same app, a controlled element in the test, is moved from one location to another and the only variable which changes is the network.    So then we have two possibilities.   Possibility one is that the network itself is the problem, that it is too slow.   The second is that the application and how it is interfacing with the network is antagonistic to its performance.

Certainly there will be a deviation from execution on the server vs your location across VPN.   Using the export function on the server, which is as close to raw access as you can get, should allow you to measure the network variance component based upon the difference in the length of time required to perform the same action on your VPN Connected host.

But, as you noted, this cannot account for the enture time difference.    Applications can be WAN unfriendly.   What this typically amounts to is that too many turns are required to send and receive information and the amount of information in each data flow can be substantially large, more than what is needed.   It is possible that the underlying handshake mechanism from your bulk export to your application is completely different.   One may be requesting 100 records at a time, while the other may be pulling each and every record in sequence (noting your difference of 100:1 in speed).    The constant application to database handshake for the single record pull at a time could well be adding substantially to your overhead and resulting in the drop in throughput.

Comment: The network is not the problem - i can run sqldeveloper over the same network connection, and it is order of magnitude faster. This is true for both VPN and local gigabit LAN.

Comment: And, the 100 record fetch should be adjusted by the FetchSize on the reader, but changes to it didnt help (I'll update my question to include that, forgot to add it originall). Thanks

Comment: Have you benchmarked the query in question using a native OCI style connection and pull of the data versus the ODP.NET interface?   It is most certainly an app issue, with the remaining question on whether it is a structural issue that would impact all interfaces or something tied specifically to the use and tuning of the ODP.NET solution set

Comment: Assuming SqlDeveloper is using OCI under the hood, yes it is 10+ times faster. And, Ive used both ODP and the .Net Oracle client, both behave the same way. So, the remaining "constant" is the Oracle Instant Client 64 bit version. I now have a new virtual machine which has the "full" oracle client installed, so I'll try running the app on there next and see if anything improves.

Comment: SQLDeveloper is OCI under the hood, as is SQL+ and the other standard utility set.   Something to keep in mind on a VM is that the hypervisor is going to broker access to the shared network resource and any network handshake is going to be subject to some small exaggerations for each time its access has to be brokered.   If you have a network chatty interface then not only will this be slowed by remote VPN access, but also again by inclusion in a VM.   A 1:100 delta seems long, so I am still holding to something structural in the .NET interface that is not there in native OCI

Comment: Ok test run results: Sample table with 15k rows. "instant client 64 bit" - 854 seconds. "full-install client 32bit" - 172 seconds. 32 bit running inside a virtual machine, so even with that handicap, it is significantly faster. Something is wrong either with 64bit, or Instant Client. Last test I could do is download the 32 bit instanct client and try it... amazing.

Comment: I guess the question unasked at this point is whether the client application is 64 or 32 bits? It could make a difference here. If the client is 32 bits and the server interface is 64 bit, then at some point where communication between the two apps occur the 32 bit words for the application will need to be padded with an extra 32 bits to make 64 bit words for the 64 bit components to understand. Microsoft's term for this is 'thunking' and the lst time it came into play hard was in the architecture switch from 16 bit to 32 bit back in the early 1990s. Thunking doesd impose a performance penalty

Comment: nope Im running windows 7 64 bit, and Im compiling the .net app to be 64 bit only. The oracle client actually wont work if you run your app in 32 bit mode (.net can run in either).  And as far as I know, the data itself from the server should be identical between a 64 and 32 bit server, otherwise it wouldnt be connection agnostic.

Comment: but- James, I do suspect Oracle is doing something "under the hood" on the 64 bit client that is making it way slower than it should be. So, the idea behind your response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Try increasing the Fetch Size](http://developergeeks.com/article/13/optimize-application-performace-by-calculating-fetchsize-in-odp-net). The higher that is, the less round trips ODP.net will have to make in order to actually get the data, and the better performance over the network will be. (Note that AFAIK if you have connection pooling enabled this is done automatically.)

Comment: I did try a wide range of fetchsizes, made no difference. (thought I'd included that in the question, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

boomhauer: did you get to the bottom of this? I'm experiencing similar issues. I did get a slight boost by playing with Fetchsizes. 
In my test environment which is orders of magnitude small than prod I'm seeing 1.8 seconds in ODP.net and 0.2 seconds with System.Data.OracleClient. 
The best I can get by bumping up fetchsizes is 1.6 seconds.

Comment: the closest i came was to just conclude that it is either a. the instant client, or b. the 64 bit client... or maybe the combination of both. I didn't have time to narrow it down further. Are you running the 64 bit one?

Comment: However, I don't recall a big speed difference between oracleclient and odp.net... everything using the 64bit instant client was slow slow.

Comment: I struck it because we began to build on a 64 bit environment, but with 32 native dlls, so forced to x86. And then noticed System.Data.OracleClient was deprecated, so moved to ODP.net 'instant' 32 bit drivers.
I think the 32/64 bit may be a red-herring here, I suspect there's some network related setting that's not set with the instant client - though I haven't tried the 'installed' ODP.net yet.

Comment: i actually suspect the instant client more than the x64 aspect as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem to this but it is intermittent.  I have an Oracle query that normally takes about 1 second to run but sometimes around lunchtime it takes 30 seconds to run using .Net.  If at this time I run it using Oracle SQL Developer on the same machine it still takes 1 second.

This problem only lasts for about 10 mins per day.  Also my colleague gets the same problem at exactly the same time and it goes away at the same time.

So it seems that it might be a combination of the network and the .Net Oracle driver but I don't know how to find it.  Also other SQL queries do not perform slowly at this time, just one particular query that only returns 1200 rows.

EDIT: I found out a another colleague was doing a large file copy over the network at the time of the slow down.  To prove it I got him to do it again and the same thing happened - but the query was still fast in Oracle SQL Developer.  So it is a combination of the network and the .Net Oracle driver.  I'm using 64 bit BTW.